# SSRS reporting server caching issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

I have a website (ASP.Net) which calls SSRS reporting server to display a report. I pass 1 parameter to it which is UserId of the user logged in currently.

Issue: (can be recreated)
When 2 users (it could be multiple users) click on a particular button on a website (they are logged in as themselves on their respective machines) to get a report at a same time, more than 70% of time, they both see the same report, Means user 1 and 2 are seeing same report of either user 1 or 2.

This looks to me like reporting server caching issue where its sending the same report generated nanosecond ago to different user.

Does anyone came across this issue and how did you fix it?

Thanks,

We checked the report and can confirm that under Manage - Caching options, we have checked the option: Always run the report with most recent data.

Comment: First thing I would check is to make sure the dataset queries are not using any working or staging tables that could be shared. I often write reports that do a lot of processing using local temporary tables (e.g. `#t` not `##t` or `mytemptable`) or I use table variables before doing a final `SELECT` for the report output. This ensures that each execution has it's own copy of the temporary working data.

Comment: @AlanSchofield: Checked and there is no Temp Table created in that SP. All we pass is in 1 Id and data is returned using that.